# Why is Webstorm detecting this as duplicate?

Tags: gulp, webstorm

I can't seem to understand why WebStorm is detecting these lines as duplicate code, I've looked over everything but I can't seem to find what its referring to...

Also, is there a way in which we can make lines like this shorter? Its bothers me that export.**name of thing** is repeating so much, I think it might be bad practice.

Does anybody have any clues to such issues?

I've attached images of the code sections which cause the problems.[image][image]

Please let me know if there is any additional information I could provide to help find a solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be [WEB-40442](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-40442). Please try disabling **Settings | Editor | Duplicates > JavaScript > Variable or identifier names** - does it help?

Comment: Hello Lena, thank you for your answer but unfortunately I can not verify this since as of today the issues fixed itself apparently... I haven't worked on that project anymore since posting this, when opening the project now to test this it seems the issues is no longer there, even though nothing has changed! Should I mark this answer as accepted or would that be misleading?

Comment: Thanks for update:) this would be misleading as we can't know for sure what the problem is:(

Comment: Yes that is what I also though, but though it best to ask you also, sorry and thank you again for the provided answer, I'm sure that it will help someone at one point!

Comment: Spent some time in trying to recreate the project from scratch in hopes of getting this issue back and I think its quite safe to say that disabling ***Variable or Identifier Names*** did fix the duplicate warnings, so it seems to be related to that issues and as such I am marking this as the answer.